# Secure query string parameters

Tags: encryption, .net, asp.net

I have an application which use the [Thick box jQuery](http://thickbox.net/) component to open a popup page .

And I pass my parameters in query string like this :

```
 <a id="btnShowPopup6" runat="server" class="thickbox" href='<%#"RollUp.aspx?TCode="+Eval("Code")+"...."+"&AR=1"+"&TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750"%>'>
```

This 's the only choice I have, I can't use session variables with this method or post parameters so just the query string way.

How can I secure my query string so the user can't play with them? What's the best way to encrypt my query string?

Comment: What's that eval in there for? It worries me.

Comment: set of important parameters which according to them get specific documents so if the user play with these parameters he can get other documents.

Comment: No, you have an `Eval()` call in there. What's that for? Are you putting user parameters into an eval?

Comment: yes this `Eval()` comes from grid view data source ,when the user click on the link above it goes to the `RollUp.aspx` with these eval parameters .

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: hmm , Could u help me please to secure my data ? the optimum solution is to use sessions i know but what about the alternatives , i don't want to make major changes now .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting user-provided values into an `eval()` call is a horrible idea, because it essentially amounts to a remote code execution vulnerability. Let's say your code looks like this...

```
var data = eval(webRequest.Parameters["p"]);
```

Now imagine I put this into the `p` parameter...

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe");
```

Whoops! I just deleted your kernel.

No amount of messing around with escaping will work here - it's a fundamentally broken concept.

Encrypting parameters does nothing but complicate things. Go for the correct approach, and use a session variable like the language is designed to do.

**Update:** To be clear, I'm talking about eval() in a generic sense. If you're using the Eval binding method on a data controller in C#, you *should* be OK as long as no user parameters go in there, otherwise they can cause your code to dump out arbitrary values from your database, without even needing SQL injection.

Comment: okay thanks s lot , but when to use `Eval()` expression

Comment: Never. Avoid it like the plague. It's the security equivalent of `goto`.

Comment: even if i want to use a template field and get the value from the gridview datasource ?

Comment: Like this :
`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>`

Or
`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Comment: Is this Eval a method of an object? I'm not familiar with ASP.NET (I'm a WinForms guy) - it *may* be ok if you're using it to bind to a data controller, but not if you accept user supplied values into your `eval` parameter.

Comment: yeah it's used to just bind advanced controls like grid view or list view .

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: `but not if you accept user supplied values into your eval parameter.` Please more explanation to this sentence

Comment: Let's say you do `dc.Eval(webRequest.Parameters["p"])` - I can pass any column name into `p` and your code will give me the contents of that column. This is a **bad idea**, especially when doing JOINs onto user tables, because it essentially amounts to an SQL injection.

Comment: yeah i see, Did u mean i can't depend on those values for example to delete row ?

Comment: Absolutely not. Doing so would constitute a [direct object reference bug](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference).