# What's the worst security issue what can happen by using eval() in Android WebView?

Tags: android, javascript

I've come across a hybrid Android app - meaning most of its UI is implemented in a WebView using HTML and JavaScript technologies. The app itself is connecting to the server and one of the possible responses can include `evaluate` field, which is then directly executed via JavaScript's `eval()` command.

Is this a security issue? What kind of attacks can attacker do via this attack vector?

Comment: That depends entirely who gets to write into that field. It might be safe, but it's most likely not. The reasons as to why `eval()` is such a big issue can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94020/163495).

Comment: find all hackerone issue reports related to better understand with real world case: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=hackerone+eval%28%29

Answer (score -1):

meh. `eval` might be scary or downright dangerous in the hands of the naive, but script tags are actually worse from a capability perspective, yet needed. Hybrid apps need scripts to run and can't do anything without them. Just like in a normal webapp, content will be fetched from a server, and some of that content needs to execute to drive the app.

The developers *could* put most/all of the JS into the client app instead of loading it from the server, but that gets stale quickly, or gets annoying by posing constant updates, while changing a server response is instant and invisible to the user. If the app uses a modular system and has a formal communication mechanism in place, it probably makes sense to deliver code using the same "pipeline to home" as the data. This offers the [*opportunity*](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#checklist-security-recommendations) to sign, validate, restrict, isolate, and reject tampered code.

In terms of security issues, consider that all apps are a security issue. The app itself can do a LOT more than sandboxed JS running in a webview can. There's also ways to restrict capabilities when evaluating manually-fetched code, aside from code inspection, by running in a different context, like those in node.js, webworkers, empty frames, official (ES20xx) modules, etc.

While I obviously don't know the detail of the app's code-handling, I wouldn't assume that the fetched code runs top-level (indirect eval) with access to "everything". Nor would I assume that user-created-content is accidentally shipped inside these response fields. Nor would I assume that the OS's web-view sandbox is being broken out of, or that the OS's app isolation measures are failing. Nor would I assume the app even has enough permissions to stitch all the requisite mistakes together in a way that permits anything more sinister than a run of the mill money-making app that doesn't use hybrid views. The "worst that can happen" (omitting zero-days) is whatever the apps permissions allow, same as always.

In short; your observations reveal how this app works, not that it's doing anything inherently misguided or especially risky.